# Temporary objects in C++

Tags: c++, reference, return

I was going through reference return and came across temporary objects. I don't understand how to identify them. Please explain using this example:

If `a` and `b` are objects of same class, consider binary `operator+`. If you use it in an expression such as `f(a+b)`, then `a+b` becomes temporary object and `f` has to of form `f(const <class name>&)` or `f(<class name>)`. It can't be of form `f(<class name>&)` However, `(a+b).g()` is perfectly alright where `g()` can even change contents of object returned by `a+b`.

Comment: Showing code is better than babbling about it ...

Comment: You might want to make the question *clearer*, perhaps with showing a block of code showing the problem.

Comment: I think the question is basically "Why does the expression f(a+b) result in a temporary object while (a+b).g() does not? What else causes an expression to yield a temporary object?"

Comment: @g-makulik Based on my just-added understanding of the question, the problem is the questioner doesn't know what code is involved. How can you identify what kinds of code yield temporary objects? What code can the questioner provide if the question is "what kinds of code are involved?"

Comment: @BlueMonkMN THX nice! I also got that roughly, but just think it's better forcing the OP to post real code for didactical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `f(a + b)`, the parameter of `f` needs to bind to the value with which the function was called, and since that value is an rvalue (being the value of a function call with non-reference return type)*, the parameter type must be a const-lvalue-reference, an rvalue-reference or a non-reference.

By constrast, when you say `(a + b).g()`, the temporary object is used as the implicit instance argument in the member function call, which does not care about the value category. Mutable values bind to non-const and const member functions, and const values only bind to const member functions (and similarly for `volatile`).

Actually, C++11 *did* add a way to qualify the value category of the implicit instance argument, like so:

```
struct Foo()
{
    Foo operator+(Foo const & lhs, Foo const & rhs);

    void g() &;     // #1, instance must be an lvalue
    void g() &&;    // #2, instance must be an rvalue
}

Foo a, b;

a.g();            // calls #1
b.g();            // calls #1
(a + b).g();      // calls #2
```

*) this is the case for an overloaded operator as in this example, and also for built-in binary operators. You can of course make overloaded operators which produce lvalues, though going against the common conventions would probably be considered very confusing.

Comment: Excuse me my ignorance, but what is a "prvalue"? typo, or actually a new term?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It's a term introduced in C++11, meaning *pure rvalue*. There's some information at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: @DyP: I'm also taking the OP's statement as a hint that his `a + b` is indeed an rvalue. Yes, I should probably try to make a more generally true statement... I'll add a note at the end.

Comment: Since `(a+b)` (as indicated in the original question) can behave as either an rvalue or an lvalue, what exactly determines which g gets called? Did I miss something?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: The definition of your overloaded operator determines the value category of its return value. I took the OP's assertions as a hint that his operator behaves "as usual", i.e. produces an rvalue.

Comment: It might help our understanding if the sample showed how the same or similar operator could produce an lvalue... if that's part of the point you're making. I'm still a bit fuzzy.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: It isn't. I wouldn't want `+` to make an lvalue, because that would be really confusing. If you're looking for a binary operator that *does* typically produce an lvalue, though, look at the iostreams overloaded shift operators.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks a lot for replying. So what I conclude is that in both cases `a+b` gives temporary object. Then this temporary object can bind to a `const` reference or can be a mutable objects depending on how we use it.
Actually I was confused here only. In one case we are binding it to a constant reference and making sure noone can modify it. In the second case, we are calling a function which can modify it.

Comment: @NeerajGangwar: Just to make sure: `a + b` is a temporary value **if** this is either a built-in operator or an overloaded operator with non-reference return type. This is usually the case, but it doesn't have to be -- for example, `std::cout << "Hello\n"` is *not* a temporary, because that operator (namely `operator<<`) is defined to have a reference return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes not from that you cannot identify temporary objects, in both cases result of `a+b` is temporary object, but wrong assumption that non const method requires lvalue and would not accept temporary object, which is not true.

Comment: It will invoke UB if the method `f(T& t)` modifies `t` and `a + b` is passed into `f` as the `t`.  Most compilers will catch it and prevent it from compiling unless `f(const T& t)` is defined so that `f(a + b)` can be called properly.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case, think of following piece of code:

```
int func(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    return func(a * c, b * c);
}
```

Because func takes two integers, the program must calculate the values of `a * c` and `b * c` and store them somewhere -- it can't store them in `a` or `b` or `c`. So the resulting code is equivalent to:

```
int lhsParam = a * c;
int rhsParam = b * c;
return func(lhsParam, rhsParam);
```

Again, at the end of `func()` we return a calculate value, `lhs + rhs`. The compiler must store it in a new place.

For integers and so forth this seems very simple, but consider instead

```
int function(std::string filename);
function("hello");
```

`filename` has to be a `std::string`, but you passed a `const char*`. So what the compiler does is:

```
std::string filenameParam = "hello"; // construct a new object
function(filenameParam);
```

just like the previous example, but this time it is hopefully clearer that we're constructing a temporary object.

Note: The convention of calling them "somethingParam" is just for clarity in this answer.